# SQL Command failed with: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying?

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to get values from database by using following query

```
SELECT Distinct org.name AS org, sto.ad_org_id AS wh_nearstoredetails_id, sum(sto.qtyonhand) AS qty, pro.name AS product
    FROM ad_org org, m_storage_detail sto, m_product pro
    WHERE sto.ad_org_id::text = org.ad_org_id::text
    AND (sto.m_locator_id::text IN ( select cast(m_locator.m_locator_id as text)
                        from m_locator,m_warehouse 
                        where m_warehouse.isactive = cast('Y' as varchar)
                            and m_warehouse.em_ai_warehouseparent::text not like cast('' as text)
                            and m_warehouse.m_warehouse_id::text = m_locator.m_warehouse_id::text
                            and m_locator.isdefault = cast('Y' as varchar))) 
    AND sto.m_product_id::text = pro.m_product_id::text 
    AND sto.qtyonhand >= cast(1 as numeric)
    AND sto.ad_org_id::text IN ( SELECT cast(m_warehouse.ad_org_id as text)
                    FROM m_warehouse
                    WHERE m_warehouse.em_ai_warehouseparent::text not like cast('' as text))
          GROUP BY  org.name,sto.ad_org_id,pro.name
          ORDER BY org.name, pro.name;
```

after creating this i also created a class to call this query and get data but when i deploy my project i am getting following error

```
WARN - SQL Command failed with: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying !
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

please help to solve this issue.

Comment: The error usually contains a pointer to the position where the problem occurred. Where exactly is that in your statement? Unrelated but: `cast(1 as numeric)` and `cast('Y' as varchar)` us useless.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the mistake what i made.
the problem in the above query is i'm trying to make type cast of null value

now i changed the condition to check '**is not null**' than "**not like ''**"

and even i don't need to add **cast** operation it's useless.

anyways thanks for you response. :)